# SSAS - How to configure format number for calculated measures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssas, powerpivot

I created a calculated measure in order to allow user to display the operating margin about sales.

```
ROUND([Measures].[Total] - [Measures].[Total Cost],2)
```

It works well, however I get an error when I try to retrieve the data in Excel / PowerPivot.
In fact, It displays values by using the ",." format to separate decimals and my format is " ,). So how to configure to change this behavior in SSAS because Excel cannot format the number due to a "unknown type" (it cannot parse the number).

This an example of decimal conversion from US to French format :

```
1,000,000.00 (US) -> 1 000 000,00 (France) 
99.99 (US) -> 99,99 (France)
```

OK I could replace the "dot" by a "comma" directly in Excel but it's not a good practice and the objective is to simplify the PowerPivot usage.

Thanks !

Comment: It depends on two factors: 1.Regional settings on Computer. 2. Format string property on calculated measure. You can start by inserting something like this and changing symbols "#,#0.00"

Answer (score 2):

In your SSAS project you can use "Format string" field to specify the format:
[image: Calculation properties]

In the code it looks this way:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[ASP]
 AS [Measures].[Amount]/[Measures].[Units], 
FORMAT_STRING = "$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)";
```

Use either manual string to create exact look or if all your environments are properly set up as French locale, there is a standard "Currency" format string which also might work in your favor.