# Change decimal separator in SSAS from dot to comma

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a requirement in which I need to display some decimal measures with a comma separator for decimal and not a dot and thousand separators as a dot and not a comma in SSAS. Example 2.245,89
This is a specific requirement for a dutch customer where they used to use this format for reporting purposes.
Any suggestions if this is possible in SSAS? If yes, how can I do this?
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the format as described https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132786/formatting-a-measure-in-ssas-cube

If you are using a calculated measure, you can use [SSAS - How to configure format number for calculated measures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761871/ssas-how-to-configure-format-number-for-calculated-measures)